# Enviar propriedade personalizada para componente PrivateRoute no React

Tags: react, route, react-router-dom

****Problema**:**

Informações básicas.: Projeto em React com as seguintes dependências.:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^10.0.35",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "alertifyjs": "^1.13.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery-slim": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^2.1.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-flip-move": "^3.0.4",
    "react-images-viewer": "^1.6.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.3",
    "react-select": "^3.1.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
    "react-toggle-component": "^3.0.8",
    "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.0",
    "vanilla-masker": "^1.2.0"
  },
```

No aplicativo que estou trabalhando, no arquivo onde especifico para as rotas. App.js

Estou com o problema para passar a propriedade roles no componente protegido que estou criando.
O componente com o nome PrivateRoute

Especificamente nesta tag  PrivateRoute  Linha 34 do código abaixo.:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Assets/FontawsomeIcons/FontawsomeIcons';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Components/Header/Header'
import Sidebar from './Components/Sidebar/Sidebar'
import { PrivateRoute } from './Components/Routes/PrivateRoute';
import Revenda from './Pages/Revenda/revenda';
import ListRevenda from './Pages/Revenda/ListRevenda.js';
import Usuarios from './Pages/Usuarios/Usuario';
import Manuais from './Pages/Manuais/Manuais';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import ListManuais from './Pages/Manuais/ListManuais';
import Garantia from './Pages/Garantia/Garantia';
import ListGarantia from './Pages/Garantia/ListGarantia';
import {_LevelRoles} from './Config.js'; 

function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="wrapper">
                {/* <!-- Sidebar  --> */}

                <Sidebar></Sidebar>

                {/* <!-- Page Content  --> */}
                <div id="content">
                    <Header></Header>
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <section name='content'>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route path='/Home' exact component={Home} />                              

                                {/* aqui pretendo enviar a propriedade roles */}
                                <PrivateRoute path='/revenda' exact component={ListRevenda} roles={[_LevelRoles.UsrRevenda]} />
                                <Route path='/revenda/tab/:tabName' exact component={ListRevenda}></Route>
                                <Route path='/revenda/new' exact key='add-revenda' component={Revenda}></Route>
                                <Route path='/revenda/:idRevenda' exact key='edit-revenda' component={Revenda}></Route>
                                <Route path='/revenda/:idRevenda/tab/:tabName' exact component={Revenda}></Route>
                                <Route path='/revenda/:idRevenda/addmanuais' exact component={Manuais}></Route>
                                <Route path='/revenda/:idRevenda/listmanuais' exact component={ListManuais}></Route>

                                <Route path='/garantia' exact component={ListGarantia}></Route>
                                <Route path='/garantia/tab/:tabName' exact component={ListGarantia}></Route>
                                <Route path='/garantia/new' exact key={'add-garantia'} component={Garantia}></Route>
                                <Route path='/garantia/:idGarantia' exact key='edit-garantia' component={Garantia}></Route>

                                <Route path='/usuario/:id' exact component={Usuarios}></Route>

                            </Switch>
                        </section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>

    );
}

export default App;
```

em seguida o código do componente protegido

```
  import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { authenticationService } from '../../Services/AuthService';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, roles ,  ...rest }) => (

   

    <Route  {...rest} render={props => {

        
        const currentUser = authenticationService.currentUserValue;

        debugger; 
        if (!currentUser) {
            debugger; 

           
            //não está logado, redirecione para a página de login com o url de retorno
            
            return  <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/Login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
           
        }
          


        // autorizado, retorna o component
        return <Component {...props} />
    }} />
)
```

eu não consigo ver a propriedade roles dentro de props. Existe algo errado com o código?

Comment: Já deu um console.log `roles`?

Comment: ou aqui `({ component: Component, roles ,  ...rest })` se faz assim: `(props)` e logo abaixo dá um `console.log(props)`

Comment: usando o props da seguinte forma como foi sua sugestão.: 

        console.log(props);
        console.log(roles);

 o roles esta como undefined
 e props não aparece a propriedade roles

ainda não consegui receber a propriedade no componente.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode inserir a `roles` diretamente no PrivateRoute:

```
return <Component {...props} roles={roles} />
```

Eu fiz adaptações pro código funcionar aqui, então faça as modificações que forem necessárias.

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/RenatoSiqueira/f24caaa12547badecc619f6724ec307d)

Comment: Olá Renato Siqueira, funcionou para mim sua sugestão. 
alterando o componente PrivateRoute

Answer (score 0):

Oi, Breno, usando render props não resolve teu problema? Pois o React Router não repassa props, ele as ignora por padrão.
Em vez de

```
<PrivateRoute path='/revenda' exact component={ListRevenda} roles={[_LevelRoles.UsrRevenda]} />
```

tenta:

```
<PrivateRoute path='/revenda' exact
    render={(props) => (
          <ListRevenda  roles={[_LevelRoles.UsrRevenda]} />
    )}
```

Comment: Sidnei Glasman, realizei tentativa conforme sugestão com apenas um ajuste no fechamento da tag chamada PrivaRoute

tentei da seguinte forma.: 

 <PrivateRoute path='/revenda' exact render={(props) => ( <ListRevenda  roles={[_LevelRoles.UsrRevenda]} /> )} /> 

não obtive sucesso ainda... roles chega como undefined e no props eu não consegui acessar a propriedade roles

Comment: Pena, mas de qualquer forma você resolveu o problema. 
Ando ocupado mas ainda quero tentar mais, deste jeito que postei.
Editei, porque não tinha visto que já  tinhas resolvido.